# Lookup Inline Edit javascript onchange event not detecting

Tags: javascript, lookup

I am using

```
<apex:outputField value="{!rhlead.Matched_Company__c}"/>
```

Inline Edit is enabled on this field.
How to call action support or javascript on change of Inline edit.

I am using this code to detect changes in VF form.

Surprisingly it works when I enter a value manually. but when the value is selected from popup It does not detect change

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(document).ready(function(){
            $j('form input, form div, form textarea,form span').on('input propertychange change', function() {
                console.log('Textarea Change');
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                    // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change    
                    saveToDB();
                }, 2000);
         //$j(this).removeClass("inlineEditModified");
            });
        });
```

Comment: did you try some coding on that to call action support or java script on change of Inline edit

Comment: --Updated in question